# how to write a ActiveRecord query in the controller using a db column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am doing the following:

@group_coach = GroupCoach.find("groups_count < '9'" )

I have a groups_count column in my db that is being updated by a counter_cache => true method in the Group model.

I know this isn't right.  Because the error it spits out: Couldn't find GroupCoach with ID=groups_count < '9'

I have reviewed the Rails Guides:

client = Client.find(10)

Client.where("orders_count = '2'")

The second option does run in the localhost but isn't actually returning a GroupCoach... It just returns groupcoach...

What is the proper syntax for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
@group_coach = GroupCoach.where("groups_count < 9")
```

To clarify: `@group_coach` will be a *collection* of records. So you can't call `@group_coach.name` because all that will do is give you "GroupCoach" (the name of the class). Instead, you would need to iterate over the items:

```
@group_coach.each do |group_coach|
  puts group_coach.name
end
```

Comment: yes.  The value it returns if I do a @group_coach.name is "groupcoach"  I have created two group coaches in the db and either one should come up in this query...  but they dont

Comment: See my updated answer. `.where(...)` returns an array of results, so you can't call `.name` directly on the returned result.

Comment: Dylan,  Ok your right.  Thanks... How would I add a limit => 1... the goal with this variable is to set a single GroupCoach in the Group#new form...

Comment: `GroupCoach.where("groups_count < 9").first` will give you a single record.